# Override inline style with css

Tags: html, css

So, I'm consuming a service from DRUPAL and it comes with its own style.

I tried applying css with !important tag to override it and it seems not to be working. The style from the service is pretty simple and I just want to override the background-color attribute.

```
.FixBackground{
    background-color: rgb(238,238,238) !important;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1920px){
    .Container{
        max-width: 40vw;
    } 
}

@media all and (max-width: 1023px){
    .Container{
        max-width: 80vw;
    } 
}

@media all and (max-width: 728px){
    .Container{
        max-width: 90vw;
    } 
} 

@media all and (max-width: 567px){
    .Container{
        max-width: 90vw;
    } 
}
```

This is the code example I'm using. Everything is working. The background is working, but it is not overriding the style from within some partes of the html code that the service gives to me. 
The inline style is not marked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that `!important` does not overwrite the other rules (**including inline styles**), is that there is another `!important` rule that comes **after** yours.

I would suggest using the **web developer tools** of Chrome (press F12, other browser's tools are very similar) and  inspect the element you're interested in. There you can see what rules really apply (in the **Computed** tab), what rules are **overwritten** (is *stuck through*) etc.
A potential issue is also that you specified the **wrong selector**, so the rule does not apply, then you won't find your rule there (but you know what's the issue then).

Using the inspector is usually the way how to debug issues like this.

### Example

For example `font-size:100%` is overwritten by `font-size:13px` in the following example:

[image: stuckthrough]

In tab **Computed** you see the computed values:

[image: computed]

There can you also see all the overwritten rules for a specific property (after a click on the arrow):

[image: property]

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is correct, see fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/unn3uen4/1/

```
<div class="container">
<p>
Test Container
</p>
</div>

<div class="container fix-background">
<p>
Test Override
</p>
</div>
```

In my test, the fix-background class is overriding the background color correctly.

The issue you are having must be somewhere else. Possible another class overriding your background color. Can you provide a demo website with the issue you are talking about?